# How to check each item in an array that contains a specific part of a string

Tags: javascript, string, arraylist

```
function buildEVQuestionLists(category) {

    var items = [];

    var mySurvey = SurveyUtil.Surveys.Get(CurrentPID());
    var remoteQuestions = mySurvey.Questions;

    for (var i = 0; i < remoteQuestions.Count; i++) {
        var question = remoteQuestions[i];
        if (question.IsInCategory(category)) items.push(question.Id);

    }

    return items;

}
```

This is what return items gives:`[EV10013,EV10361,EV10022,EV10009,EV10003,EV10025,EV10020,EV10017,EV10005,EV10000,EV10043,PH10040,PH10013]`

Now I would like to go through this list and only return the items that start with 'EV'.

Comment: I think that you could also check if the `question.Id` starts with `EV` before running `items.push(question.Id)` instead of filtering the array afterwards. `if (question.IsInCategory(category) && question.Id.startsWith("EV"))`

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged startswith, instead of filtering the array afterwards, you could add an extra check if the string starts with `EV` before pushing the question id to the items array.

For example

```
if (question.IsInCategory(category) && question.Id.startsWith("EV")) items.push(question.Id);
```

Comment: I am coding in a program similar to java, however it doesn't allow for certain things like; startsWith or contains.

Comment: @AndreaSpringer Is it Javascript? `if (question.IsInCategory(category) && question.Id.substring(0, 2) === "EV") items.push(question.Id);`

Comment: no, its a random program owned by the company

Comment: @AndreaSpringer It is not easy to provide a code solution without knowing the language. Did you try the above line with  `.substring(0, 2) === "EV"` ?